# Change color for different parts of the app

Tags: android, colors, background-color

I'm having an issue with an assignment. My android app is supposed to change the color of the background of all the layouts I have in my app (I have 9 by the way) by pressing a button and change the color of all the buttons in the app by pressing a different button. I have no idea how to do this **(edit)** besides changing them one by one, which I don't want because I have 6 different colors and a lot of buttons.

I found this tutorial about dynamically changing themes,
http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html
but this way I can only change one or both at the same time.

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:enabled="false" android:vmSafeMode="false">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Call"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".City"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Map"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Date"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Color"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Sms"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Developer"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Sms2"></activity>
</application>
```

Please help

Comment: It used to be that you could not change your theme dynamically at runtime and that may still be the case.  If you change your theme in `onCreate` it was acceptable.  But to see changes to a theme you would need to recreate the `Activity`.  I don't know if that has changed.  Depending on what the restrictions are you could just make a call that steps through each view and changes the colors.

Comment: As far as I know those restrictions still apply. That tutorial uses a secondary activity that is restarted every time we press the button, and then all the other activities derive from them. But, as I said, that way I can only change either the backgrounds, the buttons, or both at the same time.  And I need to be able to change the buttons and backgrounds separately, without  change it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.mavenmaverick.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button Red = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonred);
    final Button Green = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttongreen);
    final Button Yellow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonyellow);
    final Button Blue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonblue);
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    Red.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DC143C"));
            Green.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Yellow.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Blue.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


        }
    });

    Green.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#26D840"));
            Red.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            Yellow.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            Blue.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        }
    });

    Yellow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDB58"));
            Green.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            Blue.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            Red.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        }
    });

    Blue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0047AB"));
            Green.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            Yellow.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            Red.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        }
    });
}

}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonyellow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttongreen"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="#FFDB58"
    android:text="All Yellow" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonred"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttongreen"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:background="#DC143C"
    android:text="All Red" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttongreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonyellow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonred"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:background="#26D840"
    android:text="All Green" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonblue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonyellow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttonyellow"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:background="#0047AB"
    android:text="All Blue" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Now, when you click any of the `buttons`, the `background-color` and the color of all the `buttons` change according to the info written on the `button`. You can re-use the code with proper editing in accordance with the number of buttons and colors you wish to.

Comment: The problem is not how to choose a color.I have 6 buttons and each one has a color assigned to it. And the same goes for the backgrounds. My problem is how do I change the color of all the buttons in the app, without doing it one by one...

Comment: I knew how to do that. I was looking for a way of changing the colors without having to enumerate every button and background I have for every onClickListener...

Comment: @user3137018 : I wish I could understand you better

Comment: @LanccePreston I'll try to explain...
What I want is a way to change the colors, without doing this:
`relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DC143C"));
            Green.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Yellow.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            Blue.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`
every time I make a click.
I want a way to change the "theme" of all buttons and all backgrounds. I don't want to change one by one because there are a lot of them.

Comment: @user3137018 : Okay. I will get back to you!

Comment: Unrelated: now my app won't launch and in the console says that MainActivity doesn't exist but it is created... any thoughts?

Comment: @Rasmnev : `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` is it there ?

Comment: @Rasmnev : Try to clean and re-build

Comment: I saw something about the app being set as a system app. how do I undo that?

Comment: @Rasmnev : What did you exactly see ? Any elaboration ?

Comment: no... this is the console error:
`[2015-01-29 15:04:16 - PrimeiroCasoPratico] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.primeirocasopratico/.MainActivity }
[2015-01-29 15:04:16 - PrimeiroCasoPratico] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2015-01-29 15:04:16 - PrimeiroCasoPratico] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.example.primeirocasopratico/com.example.primeirocasopratico.MainActivity} does not exist.`

Comment: It«s too long to post here.. I'll post it in the question

Comment: I solved it. I don't know what was causing it, but I simply moved everything except the manifest to a new project and it's working...
hope you can focus on my first problem xD

Answer (score 0):

After giving up on this and trying the one by one approach I encountered another problem. It's explained and answered here [Change layout background color on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227799/change-layout-background-color-on-button-click/28227855?noredirect=1#comment44820109_28227855)

The solution found seems to be a good way between the one by one approach (that doesn't work because it's not possible to edit properties of layouts associated with other activities in one single activity) and what I was trying to achieve here.

It's not very fashionable because the buttons transform into one colored rectangles, but for now it is sufficient for me.

Thanks for the help!